# queue.IsCompleted returns false even when the queue is empty?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, blockingqueue

The following code never return. Debugging shows that the queue.IsCompleted returns false even when the queue is empty. Did I miss anything?

```
var workers = new Task[1];
using (var queue = new BlockingCollection<QueuePayload>(20))
{
    workers[0] = Task.Run(() => Consume(queue));
    queue.Add(new QueuePayload{....});
    Task.WaitAll(workers);
}

void Consume(BlockingCollection<QueuePayload> queue))
{
    while (!queue.IsCompleted)
    {
        var i = new QueuePayload();
        try
        {
            i = queue.Take();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            break;
        }
    ......
```

Comment: Instead of `while (!queue.IsCompleted) { i = queue.Take(); ...` I find it a lot easier to do just do `foreach(var i in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) { ...`

Comment: So if you add `queue.CompleteAdding()` after the last `queue.Add(new QueuePayload{.....})` does it still behave that way?

Comment: I was following the examples in MSDN. Maybe they should update these examples.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, won't that still block until you mark the queue as having all adding complete?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Yes, queue.CompleteAdding() resolve the issue.

Comment: The examples are updated.  It's a very easy detail to miss though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property for `IsCompleted` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267315(v=vs.110).aspx has the following text:

> Whether this collection has been marked as complete for adding and is empty.

Where do you mark the collection as completed? This is not an empty check - it is an empty check with a manual additional switch.

There is accordingly a `CompleteAdding()` method that marks that no more items will be added.

Comment: Not sure who marked this down, but if the question is about why the `IsCompleted` flag is not returning `true` when the queue is empty it answers that question.

Answer (score 1):

When you're done adding items to the collection, call `queue.CompleteAdding()`. That way `queue.IsCompleted` will return `true` when there are no items in the collection (after you have removed them all.) If you don't call `CompleteAdding()` then there's a possibility that more items could be added, so `IsCompleted` will always return `false`.